# How to do Basic URL Rewrite Without Redirecting

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

If I use the simple code below:

```
function my_custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^rewriteme$',
        'index.php?page_id=1',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

I would expect to be able to visit `http://example.com/rewriteme` and see the content of the Hello World post while keeping `/rewriteme` in the address bar. It doesn't work, though. It actually *redirects* to `http://example.com/hello-world/`.

How do I get it to display the content of the Hello World post without actually changing the URL in the address bar?

(And yes, I've flushed rewrite rules.)

Comment: Have you tried `index.php?p=1'` because "Hello World" post is a post not a page. Not sure if that helps, because the rewrite rule seems fine.

Comment: your rewrite rule might actually be working assuming you flushed permalinks, the problem here is one of canonical redirect. Try changing it to `index.php?s=hello` instead to test if this is the case, you should expect to see a search page for `hello` if it works, confirming it's the canonical redirect and not a different problem

Comment: @gmazzap I could have sworn I'd tried that already, because I had the same thought...but after just now trying it, it worked!

In my actual case, I wanted to access a CPT, and it turns out what I needed was `index.php?post_type=my_cpt&p=127` (just `p=127` didn't work with a CPT).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *see* the content of the `/hello-world` post on `/rewriteme` page you can try to add something like this on the **page.php** of your theme:

```
<?php
    if (is_page('rewriteme')) {
        // query for the about page
        $your_query = new WP_Query( 'postname=hello-world' );
        // "loop" through query (even though it's just one page) 
        while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
        // reset post data (important!)
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>
```